# Increment value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table which looks like :

```
mysql> select * from llx_societe limit 10 ;
+-------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+--------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------------------+-------+--------+-------------+------------------+-------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+-------+------------------+----------------+---------+-----------+------+------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------+-------+-------+------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------+------------------+------------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+--------------+------+--------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+
| rowid | nom                                           | name_alias | entity | ref_ext | ref_int | statut | parent | tms                 | datec | status | code_client | code_fournisseur | code_compta | code_compta_fournisseur | address                     | zip   | town             | fk_departement | fk_pays | phone     | fax  | url  | email | skype | fk_effectif | fk_typent | fk_forme_juridique | fk_currency | siren | siret | ape  | idprof4 | idprof5 | idprof6 | tva_intra | capital | fk_stcomm | note_private | note_public | model_pdf | prefix_comm | client | fournisseur | supplier_account | fk_prospectlevel | fk_incoterms | location_incoterms | customer_bad | customer_rate | supplier_rate | fk_user_creat | fk_user_modif | remise_client | mode_reglement | cond_reglement | mode_reglement_supplier | cond_reglement_supplier | fk_shipping_method | tva_assuj | localtax1_assuj | localtax1_value | localtax2_assuj | localtax2_value | barcode | fk_barcode_type | price_level | outstanding_limit | default_lang | logo | canvas | import_key     | webservices_url | webservices_key | fk_multicurrency | multicurrency_code |
+-------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+--------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------------------+-------+--------+-------------+------------------+-------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+-------+------------------+----------------+---------+-----------+------+------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------+-------+-------+------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------+------------------+------------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+--------------+------+--------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+
|  5703 | A.D.P.N.                                      | NULL       |      1 | NULL    | NULL    |      0 |   NULL | 2016-10-25 11:51:59 | NULL  |      1 | 1           | NULL             | NULL        | NULL                    | 5  rue des Narcisses        | 67116 | REICHSTETT       |           NULL |       1 | NULL      | NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL  |        NULL |      NULL |               NULL | NULL        | NULL  | NULL  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      |    NULL |         0 | NULL         | NULL        | NULL      | NULL        |      1 |           0 | NULL             | NULL             |         NULL | NULL               |            0 |             0 |             0 |             1 |          NULL |             0 |           NULL |           NULL |                    NULL |                    NULL |               NULL |         1 |               0 |            NULL |               0 |            NULL | NULL    |               0 |        NULL |              NULL | fr_FR        | NULL | NULL   | 20161025092708 | NULL            | NULL            |             NULL | NULL               |
|  5704 | A.P.E.L.E                                     | NULL       |      1 | NULL    | NULL    |      0 |   NULL | 2016-10-25 09:27:08 | NULL  |      1 | 2           | NULL             | NULL        | NULL                    | 0                           | 67000 | Adresse ?        |           NULL |       1 | NULL      | NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL  |        NULL |      NULL |               NULL | NULL        | NULL  | NULL  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      |    NULL |         0 | NULL         | NULL        | NULL      | NULL        |      1 |           0 | NULL             | NULL             |         NULL | NULL               |            0 |             0 |             0 |             1 |          NULL |             0 |           NULL |           NULL |                    NULL |                    NULL |               NULL |         1 |               0 |            NULL |               0 |            NULL | NULL    |               0 |        NULL |              NULL | fr_FR        | NULL | NULL   | 20161025092708 | NULL            | NULL            |             NULL | NULL               |
|  5705 | A.Sauv.Nat. BRUMATH & environs KAPFER Gérard  | NULL       |      1 | NULL    | NULL    |      0 |   NULL | 2016-10-25 09:27:08 | NULL  |      1 | 4           | NULL             | NULL        | NULL                    | 2  rue du Maire  Cornélius  | 67170 | BRUMATH          |           NULL |       1 | NULL      | NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL  |        NULL |      NULL |               NULL | NULL        | NULL  | NULL  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      |    NULL |         0 | NULL         | NULL        | NULL      | NULL        |      1 |           0 | NULL             | NULL             |         NULL | NULL               |            0 |             0 |             0 |             1 |          NULL |             0 |           NULL |           NULL |                    NULL |                    NULL |               NULL |         1 |               0 |            NULL |               0 |            NULL | NULL    |               0 |        NULL |              NULL | fr_FR        | NULL | NULL   | 20161025092708 | NULL            | NULL            |             NULL | NULL               |
|  5706 | A.S.P.E.E. A. GREINER/MAGNIETTE               | NULL       |      1 | NULL    | NULL    |      0 |   NULL | 2016-10-25 09:27:08 | NULL  |      1 | 5           | NULL             | NULL        | NULL                    | 27 rue des  Alliés          | 67114 | Eschau           |           NULL |       1 | 388685993 | NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL  |        NULL |      NULL |               NULL | NULL        | NULL  | NULL  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      |    NULL |         0 | NULL         | NULL        | NULL      | NULL        |      1 |           0 | NULL             | NULL             |         NULL | NULL               |            0 |             0 |             0 |             1 |          NULL |             0 |           NULL |           NULL |                    NULL |                    NULL |               NULL |         1 |               0 |            NULL |               0 |            NULL | NULL    |               0 |        NULL |              NULL | fr_FR        | NULL | NULL   | 20161025092708 | NULL            | NULL            |             NULL | NULL               |
|  5707 | AAPP de Burnaupt HENN René                    | NULL       |      1 | NULL    | NULL    |      0 |   NULL | 2016-10-25 09:27:08 | NULL  |      1 | 6           | NULL             | NULL        | NULL                    | 12  rue de l' Etang         | 68520 | BURNHAUPT LE BAS |           NULL |       1 | NULL      | NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL  |        NULL |      NULL |               NULL | NULL        | NULL  | NULL  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      |    NULL |         0 | NULL         | NULL        | NULL      | NULL        |      1 |           0 | NULL             | NULL             |         NULL | NULL               |            0 |             0 |             0 |             1 |          NULL |             0 |           NULL |           NULL |                    NULL |                    NULL |               NULL |         1 |               0 |            NULL |               0 |            NULL | NULL    |               0 |        NULL |              NULL | fr_FR        | NULL | NULL   | 20161025092708 | NULL            | NULL            |             NULL | NULL               |
|  5708 | ABEGG - LITZLER Jacques & Martine             | NULL       |      1 | NULL    | NULL    |      0 |   NULL | 2016-10-25 09:27:08 | NULL  |      1 | 7           | NULL             | NULL        | NULL                    | 16  rue du Muhlberg         | 68730 | BLOTZHEIM        |           NULL |       1 | NULL      | NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL  |        NULL |      NULL |               NULL | NULL        | NULL  | NULL  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      |    NULL |         0 | NULL         | NULL        | NULL      | NULL        |      1 |           0 | NULL             | NULL             |         NULL | NULL               |            0 |             0 |             0 |             1 |          NULL |             0 |           NULL |           NULL |                    NULL |                    NULL |               NULL |         1 |               0 |            NULL |               0 |            NULL | NULL    |               0 |        NULL |              NULL | fr_FR        | NULL | NULL   | 20161025092708 | NULL            | NULL            |             NULL | NULL               |
|  5709 | ABT Clémence                                  | NULL       |      1 | NULL    | NULL    |      0 |   NULL | 2016-10-25 09:27:08 | NULL  |      1 | 8           | NULL             | NULL        | NULL                    | 11  rue de Kembs            | 68100 | Mulhouse         |           NULL |       1 | NULL      | NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL  |        NULL |      NULL |               NULL | NULL        | NULL  | NULL  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      |    NULL |         0 | NULL         | NULL        | NULL      | NULL        |      1 |           0 | NULL             | NULL             |         NULL | NULL               |            0 |             0 |             0 |             1 |          NULL |             0 |           NULL |           NULL |                    NULL |                    NULL |               NULL |         1 |               0 |            NULL |               0 |            NULL | NULL    |               0 |        NULL |              NULL | fr_FR        | NULL | NULL   | 20161025092708 | NULL            | NULL            |             NULL | NULL               |
|  5710 | ACKER Daniel                                  | NULL       |      1 | NULL    | NULL    |      0 |   NULL | 2016-10-25 09:27:08 | NULL  |      1 | 9           | NULL             | NULL        | NULL                    | 68  rue J. Kablé            | 67000 | Strasbourg       |           NULL |       1 | NULL      | NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL  |        NULL |      NULL |               NULL | NULL        | NULL  | NULL  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      |    NULL |         0 | NULL         | NULL        | NULL      | NULL        |      1 |           0 | NULL             | NULL             |         NULL | NULL               |            0 |             0 |             0 |             1 |          NULL |             0 |           NULL |           NULL |                    NULL |                    NULL |               NULL |         1 |               0 |            NULL |               0 |            NULL | NULL    |               0 |        NULL |              NULL | fr_FR        | NULL | NULL   | 20161025092708 | NULL            | NULL            |             NULL | NULL               |
|  5711 | ACKER Emmanuel                                | NULL       |      1 | NULL    | NULL    |      0 |   NULL | 2016-10-25 09:27:08 | NULL  |      1 | 10          | NULL             | NULL        | NULL                    | 34  rue de Soultz           | 67100 | STRASBOURG       |           NULL |       1 | 388846074 | NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL  |        NULL |      NULL |               NULL | NULL        | NULL  | NULL  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      |    NULL |         0 | NULL         | NULL        | NULL      | NULL        |      1 |           0 | NULL             | NULL             |         NULL | NULL               |            0 |             0 |             0 |             1 |          NULL |             0 |           NULL |           NULL |                    NULL |                    NULL |               NULL |         1 |               0 |            NULL |               0 |            NULL | NULL    |               0 |        NULL |              NULL | fr_FR        | NULL | NULL   | 20161025092708 | NULL            | NULL            |             NULL | NULL               |
|  5712 | ACKERMANN  Marcelle                           | NULL       |      1 | NULL    | NULL    |      0 |   NULL | 2016-10-25 09:27:08 | NULL  |      1 | 11          | NULL             | NULL        | NULL                    | 5  rue Mittelharth          | 68000 | COLMAR           |           NULL |       1 | NULL      | NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL  |        NULL |      NULL |               NULL | NULL        | NULL  | NULL  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      |    NULL |         0 | NULL         | NULL        | NULL      | NULL        |      1 |           0 | NULL             | NULL             |         NULL | NULL               |            0 |             0 |             0 |             1 |          NULL |             0 |           NULL |           NULL |                    NULL |                    NULL |               NULL |         1 |               0 |            NULL |               0 |            NULL | NULL    |               0 |        NULL |              NULL | fr_FR        | NULL | NULL   | 20161025092708 | NULL            | NULL            |             NULL | NULL               |
+-------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+--------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------------------+-------+--------+-------------+------------------+-------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+-------+------------------+----------------+---------+-----------+------+------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------+-------+-------+------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------+------------------+------------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+--------------+------+--------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+
```

I would like to replace `rowid = 5703` by `1`, `rowid = 5704` by `2` etc ..
In order to get the following table :

```
+-------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+--------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------------------+-------+--------+-------------+------------------+-------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+-------+------------------+----------------+---------+-----------+------+------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------+-------+-------+------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------+------------------+------------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+--------------+------+--------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+
| rowid | nom                                           | name_alias | entity | ref_ext | ref_int | statut | parent | tms                 | datec | status | code_client | code_fournisseur | code_compta | code_compta_fournisseur | address                     | zip   | town             | fk_departement | fk_pays | phone     | fax  | url  | email | skype | fk_effectif | fk_typent | fk_forme_juridique | fk_currency | siren | siret | ape  | idprof4 | idprof5 | idprof6 | tva_intra | capital | fk_stcomm | note_private | note_public | model_pdf | prefix_comm | client | fournisseur | supplier_account | fk_prospectlevel | fk_incoterms | location_incoterms | customer_bad | customer_rate | supplier_rate | fk_user_creat | fk_user_modif | remise_client | mode_reglement | cond_reglement | mode_reglement_supplier | cond_reglement_supplier | fk_shipping_method | tva_assuj | localtax1_assuj | localtax1_value | localtax2_assuj | localtax2_value | barcode | fk_barcode_type | price_level | outstanding_limit | default_lang | logo | canvas | import_key     | webservices_url | webservices_key | fk_multicurrency | multicurrency_code |
+-------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+--------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------------------+-------+--------+-------------+------------------+-------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+-------+------------------+----------------+---------+-----------+------+------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------+-------+-------+------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------+------------------+------------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+--------------+------+--------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+
|     1 | A.D.P.N.                                      | NULL       |      1 | NULL    | NULL    |      0 |   NULL | 2016-10-25 11:51:59 | NULL  |      1 | 1           | NULL             | NULL        | NULL                    | 5  rue des Narcisses        | 67116 | REICHSTETT       |           NULL |       1 | NULL      | NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL  |        NULL |      NULL |               NULL | NULL        | NULL  | NULL  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      |    NULL |         0 | NULL         | NULL        | NULL      | NULL        |      1 |           0 | NULL             | NULL             |         NULL | NULL               |            0 |             0 |             0 |             1 |          NULL |             0 |           NULL |           NULL |                    NULL |                    NULL |               NULL |         1 |               0 |            NULL |               0 |            NULL | NULL    |               0 |        NULL |              NULL | fr_FR        | NULL | NULL   | 20161025092708 | NULL            | NULL            |             NULL | NULL               |
|     2 | A.P.E.L.E                                     | NULL       |      1 | NULL    | NULL    |      0 |   NULL | 2016-10-25 09:27:08 | NULL  |      1 | 2           | NULL             | NULL        | NULL                    | 0                           | 67000 | Adresse ?        |           NULL |       1 | NULL      | NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL  |        NULL |      NULL |               NULL | NULL        | NULL  | NULL  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      |    NULL |         0 | NULL         | NULL        | NULL      | NULL        |      1 |           0 | NULL             | NULL             |         NULL | NULL               |            0 |             0 |             0 |             1 |          NULL |             0 |           NULL |           NULL |                    NULL |                    NULL |               NULL |        1 |               0 |            NULL |               0 |            NULL | NULL    |               0 |        NULL |              NULL | fr_FR        | NULL | NULL   | 20161025092708 | NULL            | NULL            |             NULL | NULL               |
|     3 | A.Sauv.Nat. BRUMATH & environs KAPFER Gérard  | NULL       |      1 | NULL    | NULL    |      0 |   NULL | 2016-10-25 09:27:08 | NULL  |      1 | 4           | NULL             | NULL        | NULL                    | 2  rue du Maire  Cornélius  | 67170 | BRUMATH          |           NULL |       1 | NULL      | NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL  |        NULL |      NULL |               NULL | NULL        | NULL  | NULL  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      |    NULL |         0 | NULL         | NULL        | NULL      | NULL        |      1 |           0 | NULL             | NULL             |         NULL | NULL               |            0 |             0 |             0 |             1 |          NULL |             0 |           NULL |           NULL |                    NULL |                    NULL |               NULL |         1 |               0 |            NULL |               0 |            NULL | NULL    |               0 |        NULL |              NULL | fr_FR        | NULL | NULL   | 20161025092708 | NULL            | NULL            |             NULL | NULL               |
+-------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+--------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------------------+-------+--------+-------------+------------------+-------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+-------+------------------+----------------+---------+-----------+------+------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------+-------+-------+------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------+------------------+------------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+--------------+------+--------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+
```

To update the first row, I can write :

```
UPDATE `dolibarr`.`llx_societe` SET `rowid` = '1' WHERE `llx_societe`.`rowid` = 5703;
```

But How I can make this operation for all rows ?

Thank you !

Comment: These tables are way too wide.  Can you shorten them to show only the relevant columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this do?

```
UPDATE `dolibarr`.`llx_societe` SET `rowid` = `rowid` - 5702;
```

The assumption is that there aren't gaps in the id sequence.

Comment: Perfect ! I didn't think about this method and it works very well ! Thank you :)

Comment: Exactly ! But sometimes we don't think about the easier way

Answer (score 2):

Just substract the offset (5702) from all rows. Be sure to use an ORDER BY clause to prevent duplicate key errors.

```
UPDATE `dolibarr`.`llx_societe` SET `rowid` = `rowid` - 5702 ORDER BY `rowid`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a procedure and do a loop to start your row at 1 and increment next rows by 1 like this (don't know if it works but it's an idea) :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE rename()
BEGIN
  DECLARE count,id INT default 0;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT MIN(rowid) FROM dolibarr.llx_societe;
  DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR SELECT rowid FROM dolibarr.llx_societe;
  OPEN cur1;
  OPEN cur1;
  set done = 0;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO count;
    FETCH cur2 INTO id;
    if done = 1 then leave read_loop; end if;
    UPDATE `dolibarr`.`llx_societe` SET @id = @count + 1;
    set count = count+1;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur1;
  CLOSE cur2;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you change id on table llx_societe, you will break all links in opther tables that point to this table (field fk_soc for example in table llx_propal, but a lot of tables are concerned)